# Keyboard shortcut to close project in Intellij for OSX

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, intellij-idea

I have intelliJ 15 running on OSX Yosemite.

Is there a keyboard shortcut to close projects in intellij?

Right now I can close individual files in a project with `cmd+w` and and close the entire app with `cmd+q`, I can even tab between projects with `cmd+~` but I'd like to close a project using the keyboard.

Comment: thanks @DavidPostill but perhaps there is a workaround? Maybe a separate tool or app I could use?

Comment: See my answer. How to add your own shortcut.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Is there a keyboard shortcut to close projects in intellij (OSX)?

No. There isn't one listed on the [IntelliJ IDEA Mac OS X Keymap](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard_Mac.pdf) Reference Card.

However, you can define your own:

> Go to `Preference -> Keymap`, type `Close Project` in search bar and
>   set-up your keyboard shortcut for this action. Works for me in
>   `Intellij Idea 14.1.2`.
>
> [image]

Source SO answer [Is there a shortcut to close a project in Intellij?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32765430/3536342) by [fakerun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2642387/fakerun)

Comment: weird, I did a search on that and it didn't come up. thanks for finding it. What a boon!